# Access DB Error in Open Form Code

Tags: database, vba, forms, ms-access

I have created a database that has additional forms added to it.  In one form, the Open Form [Event Procedure] continually highlights the forms although the form is part of the database. Form opens but does not display any of the information that it should.  Not sure what to do.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  On ERRO GoTo err_Form_Open    
  Age_Ins.SetFocus    
  Forms!frmMaster_search.Visible = False  {Yellow Highlighted line}    
exit_Form_Open:
  Exit Sub        
err_Form_Open:
  MsgBox Err.Description
  Resume exit_Form_Open          
End Sub
```

Comment: How is it supposed to display anything when you try to hide it? And `ERRO` is not valid.

Comment: You need to open the form first. See `DoCmd.OpenForm` method here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-openform-method-access

Comment: Thank you, Erro was a typo.  It should have read On Error GoTo err_Form_Open.

I do have a DoCmd to direct it to Go To the Record , , acNewRec.

I will take a look at the link you supplied.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you, I neglected to get back and state that this issue has been resolved.  Thanks so much for your help.